# Python - TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, sublimetext3

My code doesn't work in Sublime Text 3 and the error is shown below. However, it does work in IDLE and so I am rather confused. I have read similar questions but it seems that they are not exactly the same as my problem. Could anyone tell me what have I done wrong? Thank you.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
zebra = Animal("Jeffrey")
print zebra.name

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: `int() takes at most 2 arguments` ? Where in the code are you using an int?

Comment: Is that the entire exception stack?

Comment: I opened a new file, wrote the code again and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you had redefined `object` when you were getting the error. If `object` was bound to an integer (e.g. after `object = 3` or similar), any `class` statement that explicitly names `object` as a base will cause exactly the exception you describe.

This is a good example of why it's a bad idea to use the names of builtin objects (like `object` itself) for your own variables. It's *legal* to use the names, but doing so can cause very confusing errors in other parts of your code if you don't remember that the name has been shadowed.